# Send an array to an Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, excel

I want to send an array to Excel file, this is an array containing different categories.

Each categories should go into one column. The code I have written was sending all the values to one field on Excel. Where am I getting it wrong?

```
$shop['id']=$id_array;
    $shop['name']=$name_array;
    $shop['cat1'] = $cat1;
    $shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
    $shop['cat3'] = $cat3;


    $id_excel=implode(",",$shop['id']);
    $name_excel=implode(",",$shop['name']);
    $cat1_excel=implode(",",$shop['cat1']);
    $cat2_excel=implode(",",$shop['cat2']);
    $cat3_excel=implode(",",$shop['cat3']);

}
    $filename ="cat.xls";
    $contents = "$id_excel \t $name_excel \t $cat1_excel \t $cat2_excel \t $cat3_excel \t \n";
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    echo $contents;
```

Comment: That's nowhere near to being an .xls file. It's just a text file with comma and tab separated strings. It's not even really a CSV file. I'd suggest you either use a real Excel writer library or at least try to understand the CSV format and denote it as such.

Comment: In my experience this is not as simple as this. Have you tried opening an xls created by excel? Its lots and lots of crap in there. Try using an Excel-Tool or something, or .. maybe just create an .csv. Excel will open it fine, and this is very easy to create with code like your one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this nice plugin: [PHPExel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)
With this plugin it's simple

Answer (score 0):

Please try to return a CSV file instead of Excel. Here is the code:

```
<? $shop['id']=$id_array;
    $shop['name']=$name_array;
    $shop['cat1'] = $cat1;
    $shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
    $shop['cat3'] = $cat3;



    $id_excel[]=implode(",",$shop);

    $filename ="cat.csv";
    $contents = implode("\n",$id_excel);
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    echo $contents;
?>
```